# PHP- Print The page without url and Date

Tags: javascript, php, printing

When I Use print option . The Date has been displayed Top left corner Like this 4/7/2015. And the URL has been displayed in bottom left corner like this
http://localhost/sam/abn/add_new_rec.php?type=1 . I need only my receipt. But not this date and url. Friends plz help me to Hide this..

```
function go1()
{
var w = window.open('', '', 'width=800,height=600,resizeable,scrollbars');
 w.document.write($("#printthis").html());
 w.document.close(); // needed for chrome and safari
 javascript:w.print();
 w.close();
 return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh This problem can fix at browser in the option -> headers and footers !

[image]

Answer (score 1):

is this issue same here ? [Remove header and footer from window.print()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228088/remove-header-and-footer-from-window-print)

or you just didn't uncheck to not include header and footer on your browser ?

Comment: Yeah Right. Same issue. Is there any alternate solution?? Mr.GaLaBoOnZ

Comment: try this '@page{margin:0px auto;}' and you may need to add a #container div to make your page fit, never try on safari