# Safari remove header and footer for print pdf file.

Tags: pdf, printing, safari

Hi I have a problem I need to print PDF file in safari with removing header and footer. I already have find some solutions but they didn't worked for me.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228088/remove-header-and-footer-from-window-print
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960939/disabling-browser-print-options-headers-footers-margins-from-page
https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/OtherStandardCSS3Features.html
```

I have tried all of this but I always get printed URL into the header of PDF file also as footer. 
Does any one have already have had this problem and some solution about this problem.

Comment: as an alternative way, have you thought of generating PDF using javascript and libraries like jsPDF.js instead of using Safari's Save As PDF function? This way you may also have full control on generated PDF file.

Comment: No i didn't, I'm not familiar with this jsPDF.js libraries. But it would be nice to try thanks.

Answer (score 3):

in "Print" page of Safri browser, you can find "show details", then you can unclick the option to "print header and footers" .. but I did not find the way to change header/footer.