# change browser url when printing

Tags: javascript, css, printing

I would like to change the url of the page that appears on the printing copy (usually at the header/footer). Needless to say that the solution must be cross-browser. Any suggestions would be helpful.

For example, when printing the current page, the url that appears at the copy is `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`. How could I change it to `http://stackoverflow.com/newUrl`?

Thank u in advance.

Comment: This seems quite fraudulous in my opinion. Why would you need this?

Comment: Not possible, unless you have a separate page with a different URL that you ask people to print out instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove header and footer from window.print()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228088/remove-header-and-footer-from-window-print)

Comment: If you can remove it from the margin with the dupe solutions, you can add on of your own at the end of the document