# Disable IE footer and header from code, when printing

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, header, footer

I am working on a site, and everytime I try to print something from IE version 11, on the printed page there is an additional header and footer, added by the browser.
I know I can resolve this from the GUI, but I want to write some code to resolve this.
Can you please help me and give me some ideas or examples?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bs4yi.jpg)

Comment: This question seems related to what you're looking for, but it does not say if IE 11 is supported. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228088/remove-header-and-footer-from-window-print

Comment: I've tried, but it had no effect.