# Printing feature from a web portal - desktop and mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, printing

I'm working(mainly bug fixes) for a B2B portal of a telecommunications company, and in the portal, they're having a print feature, where you can print a no. of epins in an A4 sheet or in a Ribbon format(receipt size).

[image]

In Desktop, in A4 format, there's no problem. But in the receipt format, this is how it is appearing. First image is how it is supposed to appear, and the next one is the actual print out.

[image]
[image]

As you can see in the actual print, there's an offset on the left side and the URL is getting printed. However, if you print in a regular A4 sheet, it looks fine.

[image]
[image]

Now in the mobile version, in the A4 format print preview comes like this, and then automatically triggers a PDF.

Now the question is, is the receipt style printing possible from a web portal? And how to avoid URL from getting printed? And how to handle this printing feature from mobile?

[image]
[image]

Comment: for desktop you have the option of hiding the date and source url

Comment: on the mobile most likely it has to do with css print style

Comment: @madalinivascu - okay hiding of URL can be handled via CSS. What about receipt style printing?

Comment: for the url hidding see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15150779/4613398, and the idea of the pdf on the fly is a good one maby look into it