# Disable browser specific header and footer from Print Page

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I am printing web page using Javascript but I got header and footer contain page title, file path, page number, and date. How do I remove them?

I found similar questions related to this problem like below

- [Remove header and footer from window.print()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228088/remove-header-and-footer-from-window-print)

But every solution says to set `margin:0` in `@page`

I tried that as

```
@page {
    size: A4 landscape;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 30pt;
}
```

It works fine on the first page of my printed page. From the second page onwards, the margin goes to zero.

I have also tried `moznomarginboxes` but which is deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

This removes the unwanted data:

```
html, body {
  width: 210mm;
  height: 297mm;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@page {
  size: auto;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Most likely you will have to adjust the `margin` and `font-size` if you decide to use it.

Comment: I wish it worked, but does not on either Edge or Chrome.