# How to convert modern HTML to PDF

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, pdf

In 2016, the best way to convert HTML files to PDF from the command line was using wkhtmltopdf. Unfortunately, it seems that that is not really maintained anymore. It doesn't support a lot of things like flexbox.

One can use headless chrome/chromium to do it:

```
chrome --headless --print-to-pdf="path/to/pdf" https://your_url
```

but that has no options such as margins, paper type, control over header/footer, screen size, etc.

It appears that there is no plan to add those into headless chrome as command line options (one needs to use the dev tools interface):
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=603559#c89

How can one convert HTML files to PDF from the command line that gives control over how the document prints (margins, etc., from above), and supports modern html/css? Of course, once one can convert from the command line, you can also convert using a programming language of your choice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a command line tool that you can use to convert HTML pages to PDF just as they would be in chrome. Once you have it installed, you can use it with whatever programming language you want (Python, Java, PHP, etc.) to automatically generate PDFs from HTML web pages or documents. All of the dependencies should be well maintained well into the future, so it shouldn't have the same issues as things like wkhtmltopdf that were difficult to maintain.

URLs:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/chromehtml2pdf

https://github.com/dataverity/chromehtml2pdf

To install it, you'll need npm, and type:

```
npm install chromehtml2pdf
```

or to make it globally available to all users on the system

```
npm install -g chromehtml2pdf
```

Command line usage:

```
chromehtml2pdf --out=file.pdf --landscape=1 https://www.npmjs.com/package/chromehtml2pdf
```

For help (to view all possible options), type:

```
chromehtml2pdf --help
```

Feel free to make pull requests on github.

Comment: `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@3.6.0` and `Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.4`  That's on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: $ chromehtml2pdf --help
/home/miguelfg/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/lib/node_modules/chromehtml2pdf/index.js:144
    (async () => {
           ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (...

Comment: I've updated the dependencies. You can give it a try now; if you're still having issues, you can report it on github.

Comment: Hi @juacala, I'm using your app with a problem of click-to-expand contents [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61900799/how-to-print-a-webpage-with-all-click-to-expand-contents). Could you please leave me some suggestions on this issue? Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If all you wanted to do was get rid of Chrome's default header/footer, and you control the page in question, you can do that with CSS, without having to use something more complex than a simple command line call.

```
@media print {
  @page { margin: 0; }
}
```

Of course, you probably do want margins on your pages, so you'll need to fake those. The complexity of doing so varies depending on how many pages you meant to emit to PDF. The recommended body margins in the linked Answer will work if you're emitting a 1-pager. If not, you'll need to use other methods. For example, for multiple pages, you can add body padding on the left and right, then wrap each page's content in a tag with margin for top and bottom.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15150779/176877

Answer (score 1):

Project [Gotenberg](https://github.com/thecodingmachine/gotenberg) does this and a bit more. Including [margin](https://thecodingmachine.github.io/gotenberg/#html.paper_size_margins_orientation_scaling) manipulation as well as [WebHooks](https://thecodingmachine.github.io/gotenberg/#webhook), [timeouts](https://thecodingmachine.github.io/gotenberg/#timeout), [merging](https://thecodingmachine.github.io/gotenberg/#merge), and other [formats](https://thecodingmachine.github.io/gotenberg/#office).

To try it

```
docker run --rm -p 3000:3000 thecodingmachine/gotenberg:6
```

Example

```
curl --request POST \
    --url http://localhost:3000/convert/url \
    --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
    --form remoteURL=https://brave.com \
    --form marginTop=0 \
    --form marginBottom=0 \
    --form marginLeft=0 \
    --form marginRight=0 \
    -o result.pdf
```

*- HTML and Markdown conversions using Google Chrome headless*

Comment: You seem to know Gotenberg well. Do you know if it can create fillable form inputs that can then be filled in and saved using Adobe Reader?

Comment: @Prometheus I don't think it will turn your HTML forms into Form Data Format. See issue https://github.com/thecodingmachine/gotenberg/issues/198

Comment: Thanks for that, no idea why my search didn't pick that up.