# How to hide or modify header from window.print()?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I created a view which look like a PDF document. Now I want to print it using `window.print()`, but when I run this code it generates header and footer.

I change the footer using this code:

`let footer = "Nr"+this.contractForm.contract_number+this.datePipe.transform(this.contractForm.date, 'd.MM.yyyy');`

`window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", footer.replace("http://", ""));`

I want to remove header (it generates date and (I think) title).

I tried to use [remove header and footer from window print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228088/remove-header-and-footer-from-window-print)

And many similar solutions.

Summarizing, I want to remove header from generated file.

Comment: Which of those solutions have you tried? The CSS should work

Comment: I treid: media print {
  page { margin: 0; }
  body { margin: 1.6cm; }
} 
But I have .scss in project. This is important?

Comment: I believe that should be a browser setting. You need to disable it from there. JS cannot modify the configuration generically.

Comment: No, SCSS should be fine. Bear in mind it should be `@media print`

Comment: @wannadream I found this options, but i can't use it. I need footer and remove header. The option is to hide both.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS rules for this (or SCSS, if you wish).

Here is an example where I hide the `.hideme` class. You can click the `print` button to see it in action.

```css
.hideme {
  border: 5px solid black;
  height: 100px;
}

.showme {
  border: 5px dotted black;
  height: 100px;
}

@media print {
  .hideme {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hideme">
  Will be hidden
</div>

<div class="showme">
  Will be shown
</div>

<button onclick="print()">
  Print
</button>
```

I've also created an example in **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jgpatq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss)** using SCSS and Angular if you want to see that in action.