# How to change Safari's url text when print with javascript

Tags: javascript, printing, safari

When I print page with `window.open()` method in Safari browser, below contents are default showing.

```
----------------------
| title         date |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|      contents      |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
| about:blank    1/1 |
----------------------
```

I understand `about:blank` is url part, but there is no url because I open this screen with `window.open()` with `print` option. How can I change this to another string?

```
var contents = printContents();
var printWindow = window.open('','print', 'height=400,width=600');

printWindow.document.open();
printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + title + '</title>');
printWindow.document.write('</head><body>');
printWindow.document.write(contents);
printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');

printWindow.document.close();
printWindow.print();
printWindow.close();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228088/remove-header-and-footer-from-window-print

Comment: @RubenSwieringa I need Safari browser solution ;(

Comment: Solved ! I change url with `pushState` method. Now `about:blank` is gone :) `printWindow.history.pushState('', title, document.location.href);`