# set margins and font size in the pdf page and remove url and datetime in pdf page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

While exporting my `aspx` page to pdf, at the top right corner of the page, I am getting the `url` of the page and at the bottom right corner, it is showing `datetime`. How can I remove this from the pdf page?

And I have to reduce the left and right margin of the pdf page and also change the fonts size? Is it possible?

```
<div id="printIt">
            // data grid 
        </div>
        <asp:Button ID="btn_print" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Print" OnClientClick="printPage();" />
```

js code

```
 function printPage() {
        var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>";
        var footstr = "</body>";
        var newstr = document.getElementById("printIt").innerHTML;
        var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = newstr;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
    }
```

How can I modify this print function to::

```
1. remove url and date time from top of the pdf
2. set left and right margins for the pdf page
3. set font size and font type for pdf page
```

Comment: Is this page for internal use or for public clients ?

Comment: @KhurramIshaque for public clients.

Comment: Try with following previous question, see if it is helpful:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228088/remove-header-and-footer-from-window-print

Comment: @KhurramIshaque What about my 2nd and 3rd problem, setting margins and font settings for pdf page? Please help. Thank You!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try using CSS properties

**Styling:**

```
@media print {
  body {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman'
  }
 }
```

**Positioning:**

```
@page {
  margin: 0cm 2cm 0cm 2cm;
}
```

Comment: Where to keep this `CSS` properties? I mean how to link this `CSS` properties to the `pdf` page? I am doing this for first time, please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

If it is for printing purpose, you can use `paper.css`

https://github.com/cognitom/paper-css

examples

https://github.com/cognitom/paper-css/blob/master/examples/a4-landscape.html

All available page sizes CSS available

- A5, A5 landscape
- A4, A4 landscape
- A3, A3 landscape
- letter, letter landscape
- legal, legal landscape

Thank You.