# How to remove page url when print page with window.print() in javascript or angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a function using `window.print()` to print the current page. 
I want to remove page URL when print page.
I want to remove the following URL

[image]

Here is my code, I want to remove it in this function

```
print() {
    this.isPrint = true;
    document.title = "";
    setTimeout(() => {
        window.print();
    }, 0);
}
```

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228088/remove-header-and-footer-from-window-print

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove header and footer from window.print()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228088/remove-header-and-footer-from-window-print)

Answer (score 0):

add css

```
 @page { size: auto;  margin: 0mm; }
```

Comment: Could you please add an explanation of what your code does and why it's the correct solution?

Comment: I don't know it's the correct solution or not , but because of margin it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to the following code

```
print() {
  this.isPrint = true;
  document.title = "";
  setTimeout(() => {
    var curURL = window.location.href;
    history.replaceState(history.state, '', '/');
    window.print();
    history.replaceState(history.state, '', curURL);
  }, 0);
}
```

But this is the perfect way

```
@media print {
  @page {
    margin: 0;
  }
  body {
    margin: 1.6cm;
  }
}
```

Or Use printjs https://printjs.crabbly.com/