# Remove url from Chrome print PDF across all pages

Tags: css, pdf

I want to remove the Chrome inserted headers and footers (url, page number) on a printed page.

The below removes the header and footer ONLY on the first page; if the content flows over to a second page, the headers and footers both reappear.

```
@page {
  size: auto;
  margin-top: 0cm;
  margin-bottom: 0cm;
}
```

Is there any way to remove the printed page header/footer on all printed pages, without manually adjust the system dialog option "Removes headers/footers"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228088/remove-header-and-footer-from-window-print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome does not support removing the print header and footer programmatically. Period. Try to think of it more as them giving the option to the user to add the header and footer rather than it being a part of your page which you have control over.

Comment: Shame. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

you could add a class, which hides theses elements on the page.

Use CSS property [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

```
display: none
```

If you add the [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) print, this will only take affect, in that case.

```
@media print {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I actually meant the Chrome inserted url and page count at the start and end of each page. Just updated my question.