# asp.net-Online printing of the form

Tags: asp.net

I am developing an online application in which I need to take a printout of the data entered in the form,but on that printed page,at right corner I am getting my page url (e.g. http://www.growmoney.com/print.aspx) printed.
I don't want it to be printed on the printout.
Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address, date, time etc is typically added by the browser itself and can be configured by the user. How this is configured differs from browser to browser, instructions can easily be found. However, to my knowledge there is no way for an html page to influence those settings. Instead you could generate e.g. a PDF file of the form and let the user print that. This should give a more predictable print out. Alternatively you could explain to the user how to change the settings to not print the header and footer.

See also [Disabling browser print options (headers, footers, margins) from page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960939/disabling-browser-print-options-headers-footers-margins-from-page)

Comment: +1 for generating a PDF. It's the single most reliable way to control the format of print output for a page.