# Changing "@page rule" with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible to change the attributes of the css @page rule via jQuery (jscript)? What I need is to switch between different @page configurations:

option 1:

```
@page {
 size: A3;
 margin: 0;
}
```

option 2:

```
@page {
 size: Letter;
 margin: 20;
}
```

Since these css attributes are not linked to any dom alements, we cannot change them via jQuery .css() method.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't this work ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160260/can-javascript-change-the-value-of-page-css

Comment: wouldn't you be better to have 2 different styles sheets and load each one independently? That way you can have different files for different aspects, and you keep things neat for the next time you need to update anything.

Comment: Thanks dystroy! I have not tested, but think it should work. Perhaps a better solution than loading several css files. Again, thanks a lot!