# How to remove URL displayed  while printing a web page in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, printing-web-page

I want to remove `URL` from page at printing time with `PHP` is there any way to do this? Actually I don't want to push my clients to change their browser's settings at printing time.

Any help really appreciated!

Comment: when you say URL, doesn't that display in the url bar, not on the page?

Comment: @think123 I think he means the footer/header that browsers automatically print when printing web documents.

Comment: @think123 when you print that page page URL dispaly on page if your browser's setting is not proper.

Comment: @AjayKadyan why would you want to do that? For what reason? I might be able to help you using another method.

Comment: @think123 if their is another way that's also helpful for me.

Comment: So, what are you using it for?

Comment: @think123 can you please tell me another way?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960939/disabling-browser-print-options-headers-footers-margins-from-page

Comment: but you can see that any answer is not accepted by Anthony

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a browser setting, unfortunately you can't change it and it sucks.

Only workaround that I can think of is that you serve PDF file which could be displayed inline if user has PDF plugins installed. In that case you have full control of content and user can print it.

Answer (score 0):

No. As per my knowledge.

The web-page url that gets displayed while printing a web page is a feature added by a broswers, and hence it can't be done through `php` as it is completely server-side scripting.

Also, I guess this can't be done using javascript, as said before "This is a feature of browsers" and javascript can be used to manilulate the `dom` of the page only.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you cant do such thing.

You cant change in browser defaults like printer settings, margins, or any other browser setting, temporarily or permanently, from CSS or JavaScript.

There is a @page directive in css that enables some formatting that applies only to paged media (like paper). Refer [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/page.html). But problem is this does not work in Firefox, Google Chrome, but it works in IE 8 and Opera 10.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically, you can't control this and it does suck. There are options that control this are part of the specific browser.  Therefore, each user would have to change their browser settings to remove the URL from printing.  Unfortunate, I know, but the browsers don't let you have that much control over them. One way to get around this is to generate a PDF document for printing. Any document that is downloaded and printed from the client machine rather than from within the browser will not have this problem.

Also, you may have a look at **[Prevent Firefox or Internet Explorer from Printing the URL on Every Page](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/the-geek-blog/prevent-firefox-or-internet-explorer-from-printing-the-url-on-every-page/)**

Answer (score 0):

Change Firefox setting
Go to file->page setup -> Margins Header & Footer and set --blank-- what you need.

See more [here](http://lifehacker.com/5603815/how-can-i-get-rid-of-the-url-and-other-text-when-i-print-from-web-pages)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use CSS properties like "@page", "@top-left", ...

For example:

```
@page {
  @top-left {
    content: "";
  }
}
```

I found this example on W3C website : http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/