# Get default printer name from javascript?

Tags: javascript, zebra-printers

Is it possible to fetch the name of default printer from javascript? I need only the name of the printer and display a dialogue asking the user to manually change his default printer, if the default printer doesn't meet my appliation requirement. Im using plain javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "plain" javascript this is not possible. Please add more details to your question if you're using some HTML5-ish related API.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

Related: [Disabling browser print options (headers, footers, margins) from page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960939/disabling-browser-print-options-headers-footers-margins-from-page)

You can of course change the layout of the printed page using `@media print { ... }` in your stylesheets or using `media='print'` in your `link` element.

Answer (score 0):

You may use flash or Java applets or silverlight to identify the default printer name. It works only if the client has those plugins.

Alternate, You can access it using *ActiveXObject()*. But a big note: *Its IE Specific*. It depends on the  users of your site. Even VBScript would work for IE browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
sRegVal = 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Windows\\Device';

var sName = oShell.RegRead(sRegVal)
```

From: [codeproject: how to get the client printer name using javascript](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/104211/How-to-get-the-client-printer-name-using-JavaScrip)