# angular2 - how to get printer information

Tags: angular, printing

In my angular2 project, I need gather/get local default printer(from current desktop) information.

is it possible to get local default printer in angular2? like printer name, id, and so on.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get default printer name from javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565880/get-default-printer-name-from-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

As we know JavaScript has limitations or restrictions to access OS level details.

Approach 1:

Modern Printers may have printer level webservices exposed to access or configure user settings. You need a backend system to access the webservice. Rest all you can manage from frontend.