# How change default settings for print in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

[image: issue with margins]![enter image description here]

I have issue with printing in Chrome. Chrome in print preview adds own margins...
Can I change default setting for **print output** in `Chrome`. If I choose set value for margins = none, it looks ok, but I need to get such result, using `CSS`.

I've tried to add

```
    @media print and (color) {
   * {
      -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
      print-color-adjust: exact;
   }
}
```

but it doesn't work. 
And also if I use:

```
    @page { 
margin: 0px; 0px; 0px; 0px; 
    }
```

I use Version 36.0.1985.125 m of Chrome.

Please, help me) Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960939/disabling-browser-print-options-headers-footers-margins-from-page/2780518#2780518