# Modify page header of html print

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing-web-page

I need to print a webpage. I use this javascript function to print it.

```
function myFunction() {
    window.print();
}
```

I see html title and date at the top and the page url at the bottom. I don't want these to see on my print and tried to find a fix for that but no luck. Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Usually hiding that type of info is hidden by the user in the print dialog. This might help you though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960939/disabling-browser-print-options-headers-footers-margins-from-page

Comment: use a print style sheet

Comment: Disabling that in Javascript, it is not possible. You could set the page title to an empty string but the URL is not able to be removed programmatically.

Comment: @albert I'm using a print stylesheet, but didn't get a way to hide those stuff by css. don't know class or id ( selector ) for those. Any idea ?

Comment: @Torchify If I set title to empty, it displays the url at the place where title prints. But I need to remove date etc as well. Or if I could modify those, that also helps

Comment: @albert yes, that works. But it removes margins. But I need some margins too. Thank you for your prompt reply

Comment: you can add the margins with that style sheet. sorry, gonna recommend this as duplicate

Answer (score 2):

The date, title, and URL are part of the browsers print setting which can only changed locally by the user.  You may want to consider creating a PDF output of your page.  You would be able to format that completely how you want.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to modify/hide them using css or javascript or ( programatically) but not using browser print setting. Thanks for your answer