# How to print html format while i have styled table into pdf in angular2?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, pdf

here is while i trying to achieve, i want to export my data that generated to html table, but i think the style is gone, how can i print neat table while my html table is looked like this :

```
<button (click)="print()">print</button>

    <div id="print-section">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ba-card title="Result" baCardClass="with-scroll table-panel">
            <!-- Hasil -->
                <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td>No</td>
                        <td>Kode Claim</td>
                        <td>Paid/Not Paid</td>
                        <td>Kode Service</td>
                        <td>Tanggal</td>
                        <td>Nomor Nota</td>
                        <td>Kode Produk</td>
                        <td>Kerusakan</td>
                        <td>Biaya</td>
                        <td>Transport</td>
                        <td>Valid</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr *ngFor="let claimReports of claimReport; let i=index" >
                        <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
                        <td>{{claimReports.KODE_CLAIM}}</td>
                        <td>{{claimReports.Paid}}</td>
                        <td colspan="11">
                            <tr *ngFor="let dt of claimReports['DETAILS']; let a=index">
                                <td>{{dt.Kode_Service}}</td>
                                <td>{{dt.Tanggal_Service | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                                <td>{{dt.Nomor_Nota}}</td>
                                <td>{{dt.Kode_Produk}}</td>
                                <td>{{dt.Kerusakan}}</td>
                                <td>{{dt.Biaya}}</td>
                                <td>{{dt.Transport}}</td>
                                <td>{{dt.Valid}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
            <!-- End Hasil -->
            </ba-card>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

and here is the app.component.ts :

```
  print(): void {
    let printContents, popupWin;
    printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;
    popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write(`
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>Print tab</title>
        </head>
    <body onload="window.print();window.close()">${printContents}</body>
      </html>`
    );
    popupWin.document.close();
}
```

here is the HTML looked like :
[image]

its like not formated, how can i print exactly like just like the html? or at least i can make the table neat, and i dont want the url showed when print

UPDATE :
i update my code with bootstrap css, so my code that looked like this, in my app.component.ts

```
  print(): void {
    let printContents, popupWin;
    printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;
    popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write(`
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>Print tab</title>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        </head>
    <body onload="window.print();window.close()">${printContents}</body>
      </html>`
    );
    popupWin.document.close();
}
```

and here is print the result :
[image]

the sixth column is combined in to first, second, third and fourth column, how can i make it just like my table?

when i do inspect the css with firebug, i see my colspan row is empty, here is how it looked like with firebug :
[image]

the result should looked like the first row, the original HTML is just like i posted above. Why the  out from my

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Adding style

You get an unstyled version, because in your `print()` function you do not include the styles. See your modified example:

```
print(): void {
    let printContents, popupWin;
    printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;
    popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write(`
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>Print tab</title>
          // You need to insert the stylesheet to the print function
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="correct href to your stylesheet"> 
        </head>
    <body onload="window.print();window.close()">${printContents}</body>
      </html>`
    );
    popupWin.document.close();
}
```

#### Removing page link

To remove the link from the top of the page follow instructions on this post: [Disabling browser print options (headers, footers, margins) from page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960939/disabling-browser-print-options-headers-footers-margins-from-page)

Comment: i use angular2 and the stylesheet is .scss, how do i specify the scss path?

Comment: You need to specify the compiled .css version, because browsers cannot parse .scss files

Comment: i already added the css using bootstrap css, but the table still not good, can you help me css it? so the print page table is neat, the looping still merge with the first and two column, i update the result in my question

Comment: @KeVin you need to insert the stylesheet to the print function. If it does not work, please provide your current code which is not working.

Comment: i just updated my question with the problem i have face, after i trace why the table is not styled just like the source, i updated the problem in my question