# remove header and footer elements from jquery print-this plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, printthis

I am using jQuery [Print-this](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Customizable-Multiple-Elements-Printing-Plugin-With-jQuery-printThis.html) plugin, I want to remove page-url,date and page-numbers from print's header/footer.

Also I have a query how to find all scroll-able elements and remove their scrolls in jQuery.

Comment: Can u explain more? U want to print the html page without header and footer that option available in chrome browser

Comment: Use a stylesheet with `@media print` to set them to `display: none`

Comment: will this @media print work in firefox as well?

Comment: if I want to hide page url from footer only not date and page number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling browser print options (headers, footers, margins) from page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960939/disabling-browser-print-options-headers-footers-margins-from-page)

Comment: The display of those options is handled by the print options (browser) and printThis has no control over those elements.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to set those parameters to blank in the browser's print settings. I know Chrome and Firefox support this. However, I'm not pretty sure about the others

Comment: Just realized it is an old question. Hope it helps someone