# Cross-Browser print website with header on every page with pagenumber

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, printing

I have a web application with dynamic content, which should be designed for printing. Every print page should have a custom header with some meta infos and the number of page like **P. 1 / 10**. Default browser printing options should be disabled.

I achieved to disable printing options in chrome and firefox ([Disabling browser print options (headers, footers, margins) from page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960939/disabling-browser-print-options-headers-footers-margins-from-page?rq=1)), so the first step is done.

My problem is to get the header on every page with page numbers.

I achieved to get the header on each page with `position: fixed`, but with this solution I can not achieve to counter pages with

```
  .print-pages-count::before {
    counter-increment: page;
    content: "P. " counter(page) " / " counter(pages);
  }
```

With these solution I only get **P. 1 / 0** on each page.

I tried other solutions: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-gcpm-3/#running-elements

```
<p class="rh"><i>Miranda v. Arizona</i> in Context</p>
<h2><i>Miranda v. Arizona</i> in Context</h2>

@top-center {
   content: element(heading); 
   }

 p.rh { 
   position: running(heading); 
   }

 p.rh::before { 
   content: counter(page) ' / '; 
   }
```

but current browser seem not to support it anymore: [CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28Cascading_Style_Sheets%29)

Do you have an idea how can I achieve the desired printing behaviour?

P.S: I am using Angular 4 as Javascript Framework