# Customising Print header and footer for MVC application

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, printing

When I "right click" on my page and click print in Chrome, the headers and footers seem to be set for me. For example in the top left of the screen is today's date and the bottom left has the current pages URL.

I was wondering if there is any way that I can customize these headers and footers for printing? I'm not sure if the way these are being set is through browser specific settings or something that I can change in my code.

For example I would like to put "Prepared on (today's date) by (insert name)" on left side of the page's footer when it's being printed. However I cannot find a way to actually set the header and footer values.

I have seen a bunch of search results return CSS formatting but that's not really what I'm after.

If this can be done is it possible through Javascript, application settings, controller or view?

**Edit:** I am aware that there are ways to show and hide these headers and footers, but what I am after is actually customizing their values.

Comment: Refer [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960939/disabling-browser-print-options-headers-footers-margins-from-page) regarding 'hiding' the browser header/footer. You can always create you own header/footer in the html

Comment: If you're using `bootstrap`, you can hide/show elements while printing by simply adding [these classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#responsive-utilities-print)