# Disabling browser printing headers and footers while keeping margins, but also on page 2, 3, etc

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

When using the [usual trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2780518/1422096):

```
@media print { 
    @page { margin: 0; }
    body { margin: 15mm 15mm 15mm 15mm; /* margin for the content */ }
}
```

to disable the [browser's priting header/footer](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-BtJwpiC0j3w/VUbrZrDyaQI/AAAAAAAAFrg/yyr0ACceY7c/s1600/header-footer-on-browser-printing.png), it actually works **on the first page of the document**, but not on page 2, page 3, etc. which have a zero-margin (this is normal, because of `margin: 0`).

Of course we could change the margin-top for other pages, but then it would restore the browser printing header.

**How to remove the browser's printing header/footer from CSS or JS, but have a 15mm plain white margin on all pages of the printed document?**

Answer (score 0):

```
 <style type="text/css" media="print">
  @page {
    size: auto;  
    margin: 0;  
  }
 </style>
```

Comment: This doesn't give a 15 mm white margin to all pages of the document.

Answer (score -2):

**On your css :**

```
div.hidden {
   visibility: hidden
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<div class="hidden">This is an header/footer</div>
```

Comment: I'm not speaking about this header/footer, but [the header/footer automatically added by the browser](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-BtJwpiC0j3w/VUbrZrDyaQI/AAAAAAAAFrg/yyr0ACceY7c/s1600/header-footer-on-browser-printing.png) when printing.