# How can I style my pdf to have a full background?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, typescript, pdf

I'm trying to create a pdf which uses css to completely style the background-color. I can't seem to get the css to give it a full background.

My CSS:

```
@media print {
    @page {
        background: pink !important; // not showing
         margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
    }
}

html, body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    background-color: #20333e;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87);
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Which outputs:

[image]

I already have the markdown data in json format and am using the package [markdown-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-pdf) to create the pdf.

```
import * as markdownpdf from 'markdown-pdf';

markdownpdf({cssPath: './path/to/my/ebook.css'}).from.string('# CSS Not Full Background').to("./document.pdf", function () {
    console.log("done");
});
```

How can I style my pdf to have a full background?

Comment: did you check about printer paging padding setting?.

Comment: @HoangHieu what css setting is this? Is there a code example you can show me?

Comment: That printer preference of system.

Comment: That printer preference, please check this answer to you problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960939/disabling-browser-print-options-headers-footers-margins-from-page/2780518#2780518

Answer (score 1):

try adding top, bottom, margin values to body,html element

body,html{
top: 0, bottom: 10, left: 0, right: 0

Answer (score 0):

replace page{...} inside @media print
with

```
body {
        background-color: pink; 
    }
```

Comment: I've tried replacing the @page with body, and the results are still the same. How is it different from selecting the body tag outside @page?