# javascript-css hide page url when printing in chrome (but still show the page number)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, printing

When the user try to print the web page, i want to hide all the extra details the browser is adding to the printed page, but still show only the page number.

Like so:
[image]

I manage to hide all of them with this CSS code:

```
@page{
    size: A4;
    margin: 8mm;
}
```

Or only the top 2,  with this CSS code:

```
@page{
        size: A4;
        margin: 8mm 8mm 9mm;
}
```

But it's not accomplished my goal, to hide the url structure when printing the page.

Comment: I started posting an answer and then found https://stackoverflow.com/q/1960939/1348195

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design, you can't touch the browser print dialog.

When you use the `@page{ margin: 8mm}` you make the default page margin smaller, and all the extra details are gone because they have no place to be.

Because both the page number and the page url are in the bottom of the page- you can't show or hide only one of them, but,you can change the page URL before the print dialog is shown, and change it back when the print is over, so the printed page won't reveal URL structure.

```
//custom function to fire when print dialog is closed
function afterPrintOver (){
    console.log('Print is over.');
    //remove our empty state
    window.history.back();
}

//detect when the user is click `Ctrl + P` to print
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    const PKeyCode = 80;
    if( e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === PKeyCode ){
        //stop the browser from open the print dialog
        event.preventDefault();

        //add an empty state, the url now will be www.yourDomainName.com/#/print
        window.history.pushState('', '', '#/print');

        //call our afterPrintOver function, and 'pass' the result of `window.print()`*
        afterPrintOver(window.print());
});
```

This is whats happen:

1. The user press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. We add an empty state to the history with custom relative url
3. The browser's print dialog show the custom url
4. The print is over (or, the user close the print dialog)
5. We remove the empty state, that will change the url back to the correct url

*The trick is that our `afterPrintOver` function won't be fire until the `window.print()` function will over and return `undefined`, which means, the print process is over.

Comment: What if someone uses the mouse to print or is using a keyboard with a "print" key?

Comment: A more sustainable approach might be to instruct users to untick the headers/footers in their settings: https://kb.whitman.edu/display/public/KB/How+to+Turn+off+Headers+and+Footers+when+Printing+from+a+webpage+or+Whitmail there is no way to reliably control this across browsers anyway.

Comment: @Elad Nice hack but unfortunately it is not working now in chrome Version 90.0.4430.212 (Official Build) (64-bit) . I am stuck at same problem like yours . I want to print page numbers but I do not want other details like URL , Title and Date

Answer (score -3):

```
@page{
        size: A4;
        margin: 8mm 15mm 0mm 8mm;
    }
```

Comment: try this, you will get only page numbers without headings and url in footer.

Comment: Write more explanatory answer.