# Hiding URL from the footer using css

Tags: css, internet-explorer, url, printing

When am printing a page from internet explorer v11, the printed document contains the URL of the webpage which the client doesnt want to appear. I have searched various forms and articles for the solution but the effort gone in vain.

Is there a working solution to hide the url in IE 11?

Comment: This thread may be of some use; a lot of different answers / options https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960939/disabling-browser-print-options-headers-footers-margins-from-page

Comment: I have gone through that thread ,  the options suggested in that thread works fine with Chrome and Firefox but not with IE

Answer (score 0):

Try it by css:

```
@print {
    @page :footer {
        display: none
    }

    @page :header {
        display: none
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working.    <style type="text/css" media="print">
  @page {
    size: auto;  
    margin: 0;  
  }
</style>

<style>
  body{ 
    padding-left: 1.3cm; /*now set manual padding to body*/
    padding-right: 1.3cm; 
    padding-top: 1.1cm;
  }
</style> this code works fine in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

This is often a browser-specific print setting.
See [Firefox](https://www.bemidjistate.edu/offices/its/wp-content/uploads/sites/60/2015/02/fire2.png) and [Internet Explorer](https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse3.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.bGM4gu8V2ul7jtn0lTWCGAHaE2%26pid%3DApi&f=1) examples. The client will have to adjust their print settings in IE11 before printing the page.

Comment: Is there any work around available to override that?

Answer (score 0):

sorry, we cant control the print job header and footer with css nor with Javascript, its browser and printer setting,

http://www.mintprintables.com/print-tips/header-footer-windows/

Answer (score 0):

If the header and footer is a part of your web page than you can try to control it using CSS code.

Here, you want to access and change the IE browser page settings for print using code which is not possible.

User have to change their browser page settings for print and need to remove URL manually is only the way.

[image]