# Can I remove the URL from my print css, so the web address doesn't print?

Tags: css

I have written some stylesheets - including a print.css - and it's working fine.

I'd like to remove the URL from printing out on each of the pages. I am beginning to wonder if it is impossible. Is there an element/option that I can set to display:none to do this?

The reason is that the specific pages that have a 'normal' and 'print' stylesheet have been specially formatted so when printed, it forms a meaningful booklet. Therefore the URL is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for the replies - I'll stop wasting my time! will also try to make the URLs a bit more meaningful too - rather than long strings and lots of version numbers! - Best regards, Mark

Comment: really there needs to be styles that browsers can inspect/respect and determine if the header or footer should be present and possibly what content each should display. in the modern world of evergreen browsers I'm not certain how the industry can go this long (5-10 years depending on where you look) without this being addressed by W3 (to the point people simply give up)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling browser print options (headers, footers, margins) from page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960939/disabling-browser-print-options-headers-footers-margins-from-page)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the URL from the printing page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585254/how-to-remove-the-url-from-the-printing-page)

Answer (score 41):

In Firefox, https://bug743252.bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=714383 (view page source :: tag HTML).

In your code, replace `<html>` with `<html moznomarginboxes mozdisallowselectionprint>`.

In others browsers, I don't know, but you can view http://www.mintprintables.com/print-tips/header-footer-windows/

Comment: It's worth it to mention that the `<!DOCTYPE html>` must be specified. It works on Chrome as well. But you have to use "system dialog" for it to work.

Comment: This (much newer) answer is exactly true and correct, and is completely what is desired.

Comment: Yes this works for `firefox` and `microsoft edge`. How to remove header from `IE`?

Comment: Firefox removed support for moznomarginboxes with https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1260480  css @page margin: 0 is now the official way

Comment: This didn't work for me in Firefox 96.0

Answer (score 30):

Sadly, no. The header and footer are generated by the browser. Only the end-user can change the footer - it might be an idea to give the user a step-by-step for each browser what to do. See for example [**here**](http://www.mintprintables.com/print-tips/header-footer.php) for a set of illustrated walk-throughs for windows based browsers.

The only alternative I know of is generating PDFs, with which you have full control over the printed output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I'll stop wasting my time! will also try to make the URLs a bit more meaningful too - rather than long strings and lots of version numbers! - Best regards, Mark

Comment: I guess nothing has happened to this during the past two years?

Comment: @Kimble I don't think so, no.

Comment: this is and has always been the "open, portability" problem with the web, even with a nice rich set of standards there are still things millions of people want which no "open working group" is really addressing, and so every browser is doing something nobody much wants. if every browser does this (1. prints 2. optionally includes browser-specific header/footer), why is there no standard/spec for controlling the behavior?

Comment: After six years of the original post, we still have no control over the printed URL.

Comment: To all the people reading this, do not give up too quickly here!
Firefox and Chrome both allowed me to create full paper print forms by simply using print style commands: 
`<style type="text/css" media="print">
@page {
    size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
    margin: 0;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
}
</style>`
I am not sure this will solve it on all browsers, but it did what I needed.

Answer (score 17):

Use that code.that will help to solve your problem

```
@media print 
{
  @page { margin: 0; }
  body  { margin: 1.6cm; }
}
```

Comment: not bad but doesnt correctly deal with top and bottom margin when there are multiple pages

Comment: It didn't work for me on Chrome and on Firefox.

Answer (score 16):

```
@media print 
{
  a[href]:after { content: none !important; }
  img[src]:after { content: none !important; }
}
```

Comment: It'd be good to add some explanation of this code. I don't know what this is supposed to accomplish or how. Certainly doesn't hide the url or page numbers on the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: Thanks, hides link URLs in Safari.

Answer (score 8):

you can try this in the stylesheet:

```
@page{size:auto; margin-bottom:5mm;}
```

But this also removes the page number

Comment: It didn't work for me on Chrome and on Firefox.

Answer (score 5):

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2780518/109392) will do the trick in Chrome and Opera by setting margin to 0 in a css @page directive. It will not (currently) work for other browsers though...

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your web browser. If you're using Firefox you can adjust or turn off those header and footer lines (URL, page number, etc) by going into *File > Page Setup* then clicking the *Margins & Header/Footer* tab.

Comment: He means doing it from the CSS via a print stylesheet. He would have to include your steps to all visitors.

Comment: Yeah, I realise that. The answer is no, you can't do it via CSS, it's specific to the browser.

Comment: In newer versions of Firefox, in the print preview dialog, there's a checkbox "Print headers and footers" that does this.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you talk about the page headers and footers. They are printed by the browser. They are not part of your HTML content, so you can't influence them directly.

Show your users how to disable headers and footers in the «Page setup...» dialog.

Answer (score 3):

The headers and footers for printing from browsers is, sadly, a browser preference, not a document-level element that you can style. Refer to [my very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960939/disabling-browser-print-options-headers-footers-margins-from-page) for further workarounds and disappointment.

Answer (score 3):

Historically, it's been impossible to make these things disappear as they are user settings and not considered part of the page you have control over.

http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Print_Stylesheets#Print_headers.2Ffooters_and_print_margins

However, as of 2017, the @page at-rule has been standardized, which can be used to hide the page title and date in modern browsers:

@page { size: auto;  margin: 0mm; }

Credit to Vigneswaran S for this tip.

Comment: This is not supported in all browsers: https://caniuse.com/css-paged-media

Answer (score 3):

Remove the url from header and footer using below method

```
 @page { size: letter;  margin-top: 4mm;margin-bottom: 4mm }
```

Comment: This is not supported in all browsers: https://caniuse.com/css-paged-media

Answer (score 2):

Now we can do this with:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
@page {
    size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
    margin: 0;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
}
</style>
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14975912/1760939

Comment: This is not supported in all browsers: https://caniuse.com/css-paged-media

Answer (score 1):

I've also tried everything but finally I'm writing below code to make URL shorter:

```
var curURL = window.location.href;
history.replaceState(history.state, '', '/');
window.print();
history.replaceState(history.state, '', curURL);
```

But you need to make a custom PRINT button for user to click.

Answer (score 1):

i found something in the browser side itself.

Try this steps. here i have been mentioned the Steps to disable the Header and footer in all the three major browsers.

Chrome Click the Menu icon in the top right corner of the browser. Click Print. Uncheck Headers and Footers under the Options section.

Firefox Click Firefox in the top left corner of the browser. Place your mouse over Print, the click Page Setup. Click the Margins & Header/Footer tab. Change each value under Headers & Footers to --blank--.

Internet Explorer Click the Gear icon in the top right corner of the browser. Place your mouse over Print, then click Page Setup. Change each value under Headers and Footers to -Empty-.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are talking about the URL that shows in the footer of the page.

If so, this is set by the browser and it is not something that you can do from your code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but the URL is added by a browser when you want to print. It is not part of the page so can not be affected by CSS. Maybe there is a way but it will be browser dependent.

Answer (score -1):

**This is a browser issue. But you can handle this problem by these line of codes:**

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
@media print
{
    @page {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    body  {
        padding-top: 72px;
        padding-bottom: 72px ;
    }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score -3):

For Internet Explorer, go to Tools.  Click on the print option and then page set up.  Under headers and Footer, make all the choices "empty".  Then it will not print out on your printed pages.

I hope this helps.