# how to get rid of the url when printing html

Tags: php, html

I used this code to print the current page:

```
<form>
<input type="button" value="Print" onClick="window.print();" /> 
</form>
```

but when I view it using universal document converter. It has this url in the upper right corner. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: So many duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192806/can-i-remove-the-url-from-my-print-css-so-the-web-address-doesnt-print
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585254/how-to-remove-the-url-from-the-printing-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that's a browser by browser setting and can't be set through the page. I'd love it if someone could prove me wrong, though. :)

Comment: Let's just wait for the answer. I believe that there are lots of monsters in this site, who can answer my question:)

Comment: Sadly, looks like he's right: http://www.mintprintables.com/print-tips/header-footer.php

Answer (score 0):

Just as *theIV* says it depends on the browser.

One way of doing it would be to convert it to a PDF that can then be downloaded by the person wanting to print it. Maybe a starting point is this [HTML to PDF](http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk/) converter online - try searching for more though.