# Disable default print header and footer across all browsers jQuery or css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I remove the URL from my print css, so the web address doesn’t print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192806/can-i-remove-the-url-from-my-print-css-so-the-web-address-doesnt-print)

I want to be able to remove/hide or disable the default print header and footer across all browsers when printing.

I am generating a poster and require these default settings to be removed, as its a bad user experience having to direct them them though different print settings.

```
 <button onclick="PopupCenter('poster.html', 'myPop1',1020,768);" class="button">Print Poster</button>
```

So when the above button is clicked it opens a centered popup with the preview of the poster.

Now I need the header and footer removed from the print page?

Is this possible?

Comment: You mean the page number, url, etc?

Comment: By header and footer do you mean actual HTML or the browser's native header?

Comment: yeah the date, title in the header and then the file location and page 1/1 in the footer?