# How to modify printing area of HTML page after Ctrl + P print command?

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I have come up with a page which I want to print verbatim. However, when I give the Command + P command on Google Chrome browser it adds extra information on the header and footer about the title of the page, URL of the page, page number, etc. How do I avoid this?

I want to do something like Google Docs does. If I press Command + P it prints the open document only and not the page itself.

Comment: You will want to look into Media Query's.   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries  You can control how things look when printed, and when viewed. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify, but you can try to hide it :: [Can I remove the URL from my print css, so the web address doesn't print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192806/can-i-remove-the-url-from-my-print-css-so-the-web-address-doesnt-print)

And after you can add your own extra information using @media print.