# Hide footer Url while printing page from chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a site which will print the whole page in chrome browser.

```
function do_print(){
      window.print();
  }
```

[image: Need to remove url marked in blue]

Comment: This is generally configured in the browser settings, but a possible code solution can be found here --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585254/how-to-remove-the-url-from-the-printing-page

Comment: None of its answer related to hiding footer from CSS. Please remove it from duplicate

Comment: @RanjithKumar No.check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36598707/6235047

Comment: There might be something you can do for FireFox and Edge, but I'm not sure about Chrome - see here -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192806/can-i-remove-the-url-from-my-print-css-so-the-web-address-doesnt-print