# remove url footer in print page but not page number using css or Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

i tried to remove URL from the page of bottom line. But, I need page number in bottom on page. How can i do this process. Anyone help me. I'm using the css and javascript code. can anyone send the sample code.

Regards,

Isai

Comment: Please share your code ?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the URL from the printing page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585254/how-to-remove-the-url-from-the-printing-page)

Comment: @rblarsen the solution in that question removes everything from footer. OP wants to remove the URL and keep page number.