# Print command for printing contents through Mysql

Tags: javascript, css, mysql, printing

I know how to give the command for print in `PHP` file but it prints the whole page.

I only need to print some text from that page, only [image: See Image] from my [webpage](http://whspr.epizy.com/result.php?arn=ZM2017AS11D568).

This is how I echo the result:

```
<table id="myHeader" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-responsive"><thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Sr.</th>
                <th>Question</th>
                <th class="mobiile">Your Answer</th>
                <th>Right Answer</th>
                <th>Marks</th>
              </tr>
</thead><tbody>           
<?php   
    $i=0;
        while($lrow=$lstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            extract($lrow);
            $i++;

?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
<td><?php $qrn = $QRN; ?><?php 
$qilstmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM mcq WHERE QRN=:lrn ");
$qilstmt->bindparam(":lrn",$qrn);
$qilstmt->execute();
$qilr=$qilstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$qiilstmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tf WHERE QRN=:lrn ");
$qiilstmt->bindparam(":lrn",$qrn);
$qiilstmt->execute();
$qiilr=$qiilstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
$qiiilstmt = $user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM fb WHERE QRN=:lrn ");
$qiiilstmt->bindparam(":lrn",$qrn);
$qiiilstmt->execute();
$qiiilr=$qiiilstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($qilstmt->rowCount() == 1){
echo $qilr['Question']; 
}
elseif($qiilstmt->rowCount() == 1){
echo $qiilr['Question']."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(True OR False)"; 
}
 else { 
echo $qiiilr['Question'];  }?></td>
<td><?php 
if($Ans == ""){
    echo "No Answer";
}
else {echo $Ans;} ?></td>
<td><?php 
if($qilstmt->rowCount() == 1){
echo $rans = $qilr['RO']; 
}
elseif($qiilstmt->rowCount() == 1){
echo $rans = $qiilr['RO']; 
}
 else { 
echo $rans = $qiiilr['RO'];  }?></td>
<td><?php
if($rans == $Ans){
    $calc = $user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM students_records WHERE ARN=:lrn ");
$calc->bindparam(":lrn",$arn);
$calc->execute();
$calcRow=$calc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$fcalc = $calcRow['Marks'];
$lcalc = $fcalc + 1;
if($calcRow['Fixed'] == "N"){
$arecord = $user->runQuery("UPDATE students_records SET Marks=:user_arn WHERE ARN=:user_qrn");
$arecord->bindparam(":user_qrn",$arn);
$arecord->bindparam(":user_arn",$lcalc);
$arecord->execute();
}
    echo $mci = "1";
}
else {echo "0";}?></td></tr>
    <?php
    }
    $llcalc = "Y";
    $updatel = $user->runQuery("UPDATE students_records SET Fixed=:user_larn WHERE ARN=:user_lqrn");
$updatel->bindparam(":user_lqrn",$arn);
$updatel->bindparam(":user_larn",$llcalc);
$updatel->execute();
    ?>
<tr>
<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td><td></td><td></td>
<td><strong>Total:</strong></td>
<td><strong><?php
$tcalc = $user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM students_records WHERE ARN=:lrn ");
$tcalc->bindparam(":lrn",$arn);
$tcalc->execute();
$tcalcRow=$tcalc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $total = $tcalcRow['Marks'];
?></strong></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
<?php
}
?>
```

So, I want to know what command should I give to print button, so that it prints the above code only and not the whole webpage....

Thanks in Advance

Comment: PHP has very little to do with this. Go research how print stylesheets work.

Comment: You need to create a CSS file to handle the look of your page when you want to print it

Comment: @CBroe So, how to do that? Any small example which can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CBroe said, this has nothing to do with PHP, you need to use CSS for this.

There are a lot of ways to make a CSS for print, IMHO the best way is to use HTML:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">`

where `media="print"` is the part that tells the browser which CSS to use for printing.

In your **print.css** you can customize your page the way you want, for instance, if you don't want to display images in your printed page, just added it in there :

```
/* for example you don't need a navbar on a printed page. */
.navbar {
    display: none;
}
```

And by looking at your print button, it does not seem to work, add the following code to it :

```
<button class="btn btn-large btn-success" onClick="window.print()">Print</button>
```

Comment: As what to print, is defined by `php` & `MySQL` so, `PHP` code in `css` file?

Comment: No, you need to separate the content of your page, from what's going to be printed, I mean with print CSS your page style only changes on print, and you keep the good-looking page on website as it is.

Comment: So, I should just add `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">` at my http://whspr.epizy.com/result.php ?

Comment: Yes, and add the code for printing in your button (I edited my answer) and define how your page should appear in the print, I'll update my answer with a more concrete example

Comment: Thanks, and how to remove `http://whspr.epizy.com/result.php?arn=ZM2017AS11D568` written in bottom-left corner?

Comment: Date,Title also are visible, how to remove them?

Comment: Those are added by the browsers, each browser add those data in some format, I'll look it up if there's a way to remove them

Comment: Check these answers : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960939/disabling-browser-print-options-headers-footers-margins-from-page

and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585254/how-to-remove-the-url-from-the-printing-page

Comment: Thanks a lot, and the last question, if my paper width is just 2-5 inch (thermal roll) then I have to set all my content within 2-5 inch of the `HTML` page, Am I **Right**?

Comment: No, I think that's configured before printing, it's like printing settings, just like the page view: portrait or landscape!