# How to remove unwanted content like url while print automatically in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying print my page automatically using jQuery.But problem is red dot circle appear.So how to remove them ?3

This is my html file look like

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    Hello From Other side
</div>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        window.print();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So i want to remove that red dot circle part like url name and title Name.

[image]

Comment: go into more settings and untick the options headers and footers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Try this from this link [How to remove the URL from the printing page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585254/how-to-remove-the-url-from-the-printing-page)

```
   <style media="print">
        @page {
            size: auto;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

its a browser default behaviour. you should unchecked the header checkbox

[image]