# Firefox Won't Print Image Max-Centered

Tags: css, svg, firefox, printing, centering

Although I've succeeded in making an image be as large as it can be, and centered onto a webpage, I cannot seem to get Firefox to **print** this image centered onto the page at max size. You can see the page [here](http://www.lonniebest.com/protractor/), and `ctrl+p` should show a [print-preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojeAE.png).

While the image is centered properly on the web page, notice that it is **not** centered in the [print-preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojeAE.png) or upon the printed page.

```css
html,body{margin:0; padding:0;} 
@media all
{
  img
  {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
@page{size: landscape letter;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Protractor</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHN0eWxlPSJmb250LXNpemU6MTYuNHB4O3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDouODEiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA0NTYgMjY0Ij48dGV4dCB4PSIyMjQiIHk9Ii00MDEiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOiMxMjE1MTM7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDkwKSI+MDwvdGV4dD48dGV4dCB4PSIyMTQiIHk9Ii00MTkiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOiMxMjE1MTM7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDkwKSI+MTgwPC90ZXh0Pjx0ZXh0IHg9IjI1NCIgeT0iLTM1OSIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6IzEyMTUxMztzdHJva2U6IzM0NjVhNCIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoODApIj4xMDwvdGV4dD48dGV4dCB4PSIyNDgiIHk9Ii0zNzciIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOiMxMjE1MTM7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDgwKSI+MTcwPC90ZXh0Pjx0ZXh0IHg9IjI4NCIgeT0iLTMxMCIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6IzEyMTUxMztzdHJva2U6IzM0NjVhNCIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoNzApIj4yMDwvdGV4dD48dGV4dCB4PSIyNzYiIHk9Ii0zMjkiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOiMxMjE1MTM7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDcwKSI+MTYwPC90ZXh0Pjx0ZXh0IHg9IjMwNCIgeT0iLTI1NyIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6IzEyMTUxMztzdHJva2U6IzM0NjVhNCIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoNjApIj4zMDwvdGV4dD48dGV4dCB4PSIyOTUiIHk9Ii0yNzUiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOiMxMjE1MTM7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDYwKSI+MTUwPC90ZXh0Pjx0ZXh0IHg9IjMxMiIgeT0iLTIwMSIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6IzEyMTUxMztzdHJva2U6IzM0NjVhNCIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoNTApIj40MDwvdGV4dD48dGV4dCB4PSIzMDYiIHk9Ii0yMjEiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOiMxMjE1MTM7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDUwKSI+MTQwPC90ZXh0Pjx0ZXh0IHg9IjMxMSIgeT0iLTE0NyIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6IzEyMTUxMztzdHJva2U6IzM0NjVhNCIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoNDApIj41MDwvdGV4dD48dGV4dCB4PSIzMDciIHk9Ii0xNjQiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOiMxMjE1MTM7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDQwKSI+MTMwPC90ZXh0Pjx0ZXh0IHg9IjMwMiIgeT0iLTkxIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDojMTIxNTEzO3N0cm9rZTojMzQ2NWE0IiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgzMCkiPjYwPC90ZXh0Pjx0ZXh0IHg9IjI5NyIgeT0iLTExMCIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6IzEyMTUxMztzdHJva2U6IzM0NjVhNCIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMzApIj4xMjA8L3RleHQ+PHRleHQgeD0iMjg0IiB5PSItMzgiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOiMxMjE1MTM7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDIwKSI+NzA8L3RleHQ+PHRleHQgeD0iMjc4IiB5PSItNTciIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOiMxMjE1MTM7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDIwKSI+MTEwPC90ZXh0Pjx0ZXh0IHg9IjI1NyIgeT0iMTAiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOiMxMjE1MTM7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDEwKSI+ODA8L3RleHQ+PHRleHQgeD0iMjUwIiB5PSItOCIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6IzEyMTUxMztzdHJva2U6IzM0NjVhNCIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTApIj4xMDA8L3RleHQ+PHRleHQgeD0iMjEzIiB5PSI0NSIgc3R5bGU9ImZvbnQtc2l6ZToyNy45cHg7ZmlsbDojMTIxNTEzO3N0cm9rZTojMzQ2NWE0O3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDoxLjM3Ij45MDwvdGV4dD48dGV4dCB4PSIxNzEiIHk9Ijg5IiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDojMTIxNTEzO3N0cm9rZTojMzQ2NWE0IiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgtMTApIj4xMDA8L3RleHQ+PHRleHQgeD0iMTc3IiB5PSI3MSIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6IzEyMTUxMztzdHJva2U6IzM0NjVhNCIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoLTEwKSI+ODA8L3RleHQ+PHRleHQgeD0iMTIzIiB5PSIxMTciIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOiMxMjE1MTM7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKC0yMCkiPjExMDwvdGV4dD48dGV4dCB4PSIxMjkiIHk9IjEwMCIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6IzEyMTUxMztzdHJva2U6IzM0NjVhNCIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoLTIwKSI+NzA8L3RleHQ+PHRleHQgeD0iNjkiIHk9IjEzNiIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6IzEyMTUxMztzdHJva2U6IzM0NjVhNCIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoLTMwKSI+MTIwPC90ZXh0Pjx0ZXh0IHg9Ijc1IiB5PSIxMTgiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOiMxMjE1MTM7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKC0zMCkiPjYwPC90ZXh0Pjx0ZXh0IHg9IjEzIiB5PSIxNDYiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOiMxMjE1MTM7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKC00MCkiPjEzMDwvdGV4dD48dGV4dCB4PSIxOSIgeT0iMTI4IiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDojMTIxNTEzO3N0cm9rZTojMzQ2NWE0IiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgtNDApIj41MDwvdGV4dD48dGV4dCB4PSItNDIiIHk9IjE0NyIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6IzEyMTUxMztzdHJva2U6IzM0NjVhNCIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoLTUwKSI+MTQwPC90ZXh0Pjx0ZXh0IHg9Ii0zOCIgeT0iMTI4IiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDojMTIxNTEzO3N0cm9rZTojMzQ2NWE0IiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgtNTApIj40MDwvdGV4dD48dGV4dCB4PSItOTgiIHk9IjEzNiIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6IzEyMTUxMztzdHJva2U6IzM0NjVhNCIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoLTYwKSI+MTUwPC90ZXh0Pjx0ZXh0IHg9Ii05NSIgeT0iMTE5IiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDojMTIxNTEzO3N0cm9rZTojMzQ2NWE0IiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgtNjApIj4zMDwvdGV4dD48dGV4dCB4PSItMTUxIiB5PSIxMTciIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOiMxMjE1MTM7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKC03MCkiPjE2MDwvdGV4dD48dGV4dCB4PSItMTQ4IiB5PSIxMDAiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOiMxMjE1MTM7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKC03MCkiPjIwPC90ZXh0Pjx0ZXh0IHg9Ii0yMDEiIHk9Ijg5IiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDojMTIxNTEzO3N0cm9rZTojMzQ2NWE0IiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgtODApIj4xNzA8L3RleHQ+PHRleHQgeD0iLTE5NyIgeT0iNzEiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOiMxMjE1MTM7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKC04MCkiPjEwPC90ZXh0Pjx0ZXh0IHg9Ii0yNDYiIHk9IjUyIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDojMTIxNTEzO3N0cm9rZTojMzQ2NWE0IiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgtOTApIj4xODA8L3RleHQ+PHRleHQgeD0iLTIzNCIgeT0iMzQiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOiMxMjE1MTM7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKC05MCkiPjA8L3RleHQ+PHBhdGggZD0iTTIyOCAxQTIyNyAyMjcgMCAwIDAgMyAyNjNoNDQ5QTIyNyAyMjcgMCAwIDAgMjI4IDF6IiBzdHlsZT0iY29sb3I6IzAwMDtvdmVyZmxvdzp2aXNpYmxlO2ZpbGw6bm9uZTtzdHJva2U6IzM0NjVhNDtzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg6MS4zOTtzdHJva2UtbGluZWpvaW46cm91bmQiLz48cGF0aCBkPSJNNTg1IDMwMGgyNSIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6bm9uZTtzdHJva2U6IzM0NjVhNDtzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg6NC4wOSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJ0cmFuc2xhdGUoOCA5KSBzY2FsZSguNzMzMjgpIi8+PHBhdGggZD0ibTU4NCAyNzUgMjUtMiIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6bm9uZTtzdHJva2U6IzM0NjVhNDtzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg6MS44OCIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJ0cmFuc2xhdGUoOCA5KSBzY2FsZSguNzMzMjgpIi8+PHBhdGggZD0ibTMzMCAyOTUgMTk3LTM1IiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDpub25lO3N0cm9rZTojMzQ2NWE0O3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDoxLjIzIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InRyYW5zbGF0ZSg4IDkpIHNjYWxlKC43MzMyOCkiLz48cGF0aCBkPSJtNTgxIDI1MSAyNC01bS0zMC0yMCAyNC02IiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDpub25lO3N0cm9rZTojMzQ2NWE0O3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDoxLjg4IiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InRyYW5zbGF0ZSg4IDkpIHNjYWxlKC43MzMyOCkiLz48cGF0aCBkPSJtMzI4IDI5MCAxODgtNjkiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOm5vbmU7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQ7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjEuMjMiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDggOSkgc2NhbGUoLjczMzI4KSIvPjxwYXRoIGQ9Im01NjggMjAzIDIzLTltLTMzLTE0IDIzLTExIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDpub25lO3N0cm9rZTojMzQ2NWE0O3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDoxLjg4IiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InRyYW5zbGF0ZSg4IDkpIHNjYWxlKC43MzMyOCkiLz48cGF0aCBkPSJtMzI2IDI4NSAxNzMtMTAwIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDpub25lO3N0cm9rZTojMzQ2NWE0O3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDoxLjIzIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InRyYW5zbGF0ZSg4IDkpIHNjYWxlKC43MzMyOCkiLz48cGF0aCBkPSJtNTQ3IDE1OCAyMS0xM20tMzUtOCAyMS0xNSIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6bm9uZTtzdHJva2U6IzM0NjVhNDtzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg6MS44OCIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJ0cmFuc2xhdGUoOCA5KSBzY2FsZSguNzMzMjgpIi8+PHBhdGggZD0ibTMyMyAyODEgMTUzLTEyOSIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6bm9uZTtzdHJva2U6IzM0NjVhNDtzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg6MS4yMyIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJ0cmFuc2xhdGUoOCA5KSBzY2FsZSguNzMzMjgpIi8+PHBhdGggZD0ibTUxOCAxMTcgMTktMTYiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOm5vbmU7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQ7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjEuODgiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDggOSkgc2NhbGUoLjczMzI4KSIvPjxwYXRoIGQ9Im01MDIgOTggMTctMTciIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOm5vbmU7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQ7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjQuMDkiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDggOSkgc2NhbGUoLjczMzI4KSIvPjxwYXRoIGQ9Im0zMTkgMjc3IDEyOS0xNTMiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOm5vbmU7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQ7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjEuMjMiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDggOSkgc2NhbGUoLjczMzI4KSIvPjxwYXRoIGQ9Im00ODMgODIgMTYtMTltLTM2IDQgMTUtMjEiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOm5vbmU7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQ7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjEuODgiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDggOSkgc2NhbGUoLjczMzI4KSIvPjxwYXRoIGQ9Im0zMTUgMjc0IDEwMC0xNzMiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOm5vbmU7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQ7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjEuMjMiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDggOSkgc2NhbGUoLjczMzI4KSIvPjxwYXRoIGQ9Im00NDMgNTMgMTItMjFtLTM1IDEwIDExLTIzIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDpub25lO3N0cm9rZTojMzQ2NWE0O3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDoxLjg4IiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InRyYW5zbGF0ZSg4IDkpIHNjYWxlKC43MzMyOCkiLz48cGF0aCBkPSJtMzEwIDI3MiA2OS0xODgiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOm5vbmU7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQ7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjEuMjMiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDggOSkgc2NhbGUoLjczMzI4KSIvPjxwYXRoIGQ9Im0zOTcgMzIgOS0yM20tMzIgMTYgNi0yNCIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6bm9uZTtzdHJva2U6IzM0NjVhNDtzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg6MS44OCIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJ0cmFuc2xhdGUoOCA5KSBzY2FsZSguNzMzMjgpIi8+PHBhdGggZD0ibTMwNSAyNzAgMzUtMTk3IiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDpub25lO3N0cm9rZTojMzQ2NWE0O3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDoxLjIzIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InRyYW5zbGF0ZSg4IDkpIHNjYWxlKC43MzMyOCkiLz48cGF0aCBkPSJtMzQ5IDE5IDUtMjRtLTI5IDIxIDItMjUiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOm5vbmU7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQ7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjEuODgiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDggOSkgc2NhbGUoLjczMzI4KSIvPjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0zMDAgMjcwVjcwIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDpub25lO3N0cm9rZTojMzQ2NWE0O3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDoyLjk1IiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09Im1hdHJpeCguMTc0OTYgMCAwIC45NDYwNyAxNzYgLTYpIi8+PHBhdGggZD0iTTMwMCAxNXYtMjUiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOm5vbmU7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQ7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjQuMTgiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDggOSkgc2NhbGUoLjczMzI4KSIvPjxwYXRoIGQ9Im0yNzUgMTYtMi0yNSIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6bm9uZTtzdHJva2U6IzM0NjVhNDtzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg6MS44OCIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJ0cmFuc2xhdGUoOCA5KSBzY2FsZSguNzMzMjgpIi8+PHBhdGggZD0iTTI5NSAyNzAgMjYwIDczIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDpub25lO3N0cm9rZTojMzQ2NWE0O3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDoxLjIzIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InRyYW5zbGF0ZSg4IDkpIHNjYWxlKC43MzMyOCkiLz48cGF0aCBkPSJtMjUxIDE5LTUtMjRtLTIwIDMwLTYtMjQiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOm5vbmU7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQ7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjEuODgiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDggOSkgc2NhbGUoLjczMzI4KSIvPjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0yOTAgMjcyIDIyMSA4NCIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6bm9uZTtzdHJva2U6IzM0NjVhNDtzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg6MS4yMyIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJ0cmFuc2xhdGUoOCA5KSBzY2FsZSguNzMzMjgpIi8+PHBhdGggZD0ibTIwMyAzMi05LTIzbS0xNCAzMy0xMS0yMyIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6bm9uZTtzdHJva2U6IzM0NjVhNDtzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg6MS44OCIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJ0cmFuc2xhdGUoOCA5KSBzY2FsZSguNzMzMjgpIi8+PHBhdGggZD0iTTI4NSAyNzQgMTg1IDEwMSIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6bm9uZTtzdHJva2U6IzM0NjVhNDtzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg6MS4yMyIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJ0cmFuc2xhdGUoOCA5KSBzY2FsZSguNzMzMjgpIi8+PHBhdGggZD0ibTE1OCA1My0xMy0yMW0tOCAzNS0xNS0yMSIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6bm9uZTtzdHJva2U6IzM0NjVhNDtzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg6MS44OCIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJ0cmFuc2xhdGUoOCA5KSBzY2FsZSguNzMzMjgpIi8+PHBhdGggZD0iTTI4MSAyNzcgMTUyIDEyNCIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6bm9uZTtzdHJva2U6IzM0NjVhNDtzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg6MS4yMyIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJ0cmFuc2xhdGUoOCA5KSBzY2FsZSguNzMzMjgpIi8+PHBhdGggZD0ibTExNyA4Mi0xNi0xOSIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6bm9uZTtzdHJva2U6IzM0NjVhNDtzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg6MS44OCIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJ0cmFuc2xhdGUoOCA5KSBzY2FsZSguNzMzMjgpIi8+PHBhdGggZD0iTTk4IDk4IDgxIDgxIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDpub25lO3N0cm9rZTojMzQ2NWE0O3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDo0LjA5IiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InRyYW5zbGF0ZSg4IDkpIHNjYWxlKC43MzMyOCkiLz48cGF0aCBkPSJNMjc3IDI4MSAxMjQgMTUyIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDpub25lO3N0cm9rZTojMzQ2NWE0O3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDoxLjIzIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InRyYW5zbGF0ZSg4IDkpIHNjYWxlKC43MzMyOCkiLz48cGF0aCBkPSJtODIgMTE3LTE5LTE2bTQgMzYtMjEtMTUiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOm5vbmU7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQ7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjEuODgiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDggOSkgc2NhbGUoLjczMzI4KSIvPjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0yNzQgMjg1IDEwMSAxODUiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOm5vbmU7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQ7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjEuMjMiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDggOSkgc2NhbGUoLjczMzI4KSIvPjxwYXRoIGQ9Im01MyAxNTgtMjEtMTNtMTAgMzUtMjMtMTEiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOm5vbmU7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQ7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjEuODgiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDggOSkgc2NhbGUoLjczMzI4KSIvPjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0yNzIgMjkwIDg0IDIyMSIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6bm9uZTtzdHJva2U6IzM0NjVhNDtzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg6MS4yMyIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJ0cmFuc2xhdGUoOCA5KSBzY2FsZSguNzMzMjgpIi8+PHBhdGggZD0ibTMyIDIwMy0yMy05bTE2IDMyLTI0LTYiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOm5vbmU7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQ7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjEuODgiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDggOSkgc2NhbGUoLjczMzI4KSIvPjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0yNzAgMjk1IDczIDI2MCIgc3R5bGU9ImZpbGw6bm9uZTtzdHJva2U6IzM0NjVhNDtzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg6MS4yMyIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJ0cmFuc2xhdGUoOCA5KSBzY2FsZSguNzMzMjgpIi8+PHBhdGggZD0ibTE5IDI1MS0yNC01bTIxIDI5LTI1LTIiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOm5vbmU7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQ7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjEuODgiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDggOSkgc2NhbGUoLjczMzI4KSIvPjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0yNzAgMzAwSDcwIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDpub25lO3N0cm9rZTojMzQ2NWE0O3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDoxLjA4IiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09Im1hdHJpeCgxLjY3MjI3IDAgMCAuNzMzMjggLTU3IDkpIi8+PHBhdGggZD0iTTE1IDMwMGgtMjUiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOm5vbmU7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQ7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjQuMDkiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDggOSkgc2NhbGUoLjczMzI4KSIvPjxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjIyOCIgY3k9IjIyOCIgcj0iMjEuMyIgc3R5bGU9ImNvbG9yOiMwMDA7b3ZlcmZsb3c6dmlzaWJsZTtmaWxsOm5vbmU7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQ7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjEuMzg7c3Ryb2tlLWxpbmVqb2luOnJvdW5kIi8+PHBhdGggZD0iTTIyOCAyMjkgMzg4IDY4TTIyOCAyMjkgNjcgNjgiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOm5vbmU7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQ7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjE7c3Ryb2tlLWRhc2hhcnJheTo4LDgiLz48cGF0aCBkPSJNMCAyMjloMTEiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOm5vbmU7c3Ryb2tlOiMzNDY1YTQ7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOi40Ii8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxIDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgyIDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgzIDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSg0IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSg2IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSg3IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSg4IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSg5IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxMSAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTIgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDEzIDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxNCAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTYgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDE3IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxOCAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTkgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDIxIDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgyMiAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMjMgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDI0IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgyNiAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMjcgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDI4IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgyOSAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMzEgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDMyIDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgzMyAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMzQgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDM2IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgzNyAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMzggMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDM5IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSg0MSAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoNDIgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDQzIDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSg0NCAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoNDYgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDQ3IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSg0OCAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoNDkgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDUxIDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSg1MiAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoNTMgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDU0IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSg1NiAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoNTcgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDU4IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSg1OSAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoNjEgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDYyIDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSg2MyAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoNjQgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDY2IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSg2NyAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoNjggMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDY5IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSg3MSAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoNzIgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDczIDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSg3NCAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoNzYgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDc3IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSg3OCAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoNzkgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDgxIDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSg4MiAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoODMgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDg0IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSg4NiAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoODcgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDg4IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSg4OSAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoOTEgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDkyIDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSg5MyAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoOTQgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDk2IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSg5NyAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoOTggMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDk5IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxMDEgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDEwMiAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTAzIDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxMDQgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDEwNiAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTA3IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxMDggMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDEwOSAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTExIDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxMTIgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDExMyAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTE0IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxMTYgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDExNyAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTE4IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxMTkgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDEyMSAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTIyIDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxMjMgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDEyNCAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTI2IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxMjcgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDEyOCAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTI5IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxMzEgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDEzMiAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTMzIDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxMzQgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDEzNiAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTM3IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxMzggMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDEzOSAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTQxIDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxNDIgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDE0MyAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTQ0IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxNDYgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDE0NyAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTQ4IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxNDkgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDE1MSAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTUyIDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxNTMgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDE1NCAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTU2IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxNTcgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDE1OCAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTU5IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxNjEgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDE2MiAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTYzIDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxNjQgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDE2NiAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTY3IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxNjggMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDE2OSAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTcxIDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxNzIgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDE3MyAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTc0IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxNzYgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48dXNlIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0icm90YXRlKDE3NyAyMjggMjI5KSIvPjx1c2Ugd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoMTc4IDIyOCAyMjkpIi8+PHVzZSB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InJvdGF0ZSgxNzkgMjI4IDIyOSkiLz48L3N2Zz4=">
</body>
</html>
```

In chromium based browsers, the image does print in the center of the page. How can I get it to also do this Firefox?

Additionally, using CSS, how can I remove the extra information (example: url and timestamp) that browsers print onto the page?

I basically want the image to be as large as it can be on the printed page, landscaped, centered, and without any page info also printed.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14975912/217867), I found that `@page { margin: 0; }` removes the URL and Timestamp from the printed page. However, in Firefox, the image still doesn't print in the center of the page, nor does it print as large as it does in Chromium. This [print-preview](https://i.imgur.com/Oudwk9A.png) shows that the print job will produce a "less than maximum sized image" that is not centered. How can I fix this?

Comment: This is what I'm seeing in Firefox. It is centered. If yours is not centered, then there's an issue with a setting of your browser: [Firefox (with headers/footers](https://i.imgur.com/ZGRpIP7.png). In the next image, I've removed the headers and footers, but this is a setting in your print dialog. [Firefox (without headers/footers)](https://i.imgur.com/xTBqQKy.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `@media print {}` and assign specific classes/properties within that print query. I've done this quite a bit. In the snippet below, I've included a sample.

**Updated**

I've included a couple things that will display in the snippet view, but when you click "Print", those elements will not appear.

The print button and the phrase "This message will not display when you click print." will go away when you hit print.

```js
let print = document.querySelector('.print');

print.addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.print();
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.print {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #5CBF54;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.print:hover {
  background-color: #479D3E;
}

.print-msg {
  display: block;
}

@media print {
  body {
    color: black;
  }
  
  .print-msg {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .print {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="print">Print</button>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo qui minus quo culpa consequatur laboriosam, repudiandae maiores explicabo quas debitis beatae fugiat ad provident recusandae animi voluptates nisi accusamus delectus.</p>
  <h2 class="print-msg">This message will not display when you click print.</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, I'm already using `@media all`. It is my understanding that css rules placed in `@media all` also apply to print media.  However, I did try changing `@media all` to `@media print`. This had no effect on the print-preview in Firefox; it still prints the image left of center, instead of center (as desired).

Comment: Don't change the entire thing to `@media print {}`. This type of media query works like any other media query. You have to set up your default styles, and then custom styles go within the media query. I've updated my answer with some more information.